# ConnectionError at /test/DEF230548/

Tags: python, django

ConnectionError at /test/DEF230548/
HTTPConnectionPool(host=‘test’, port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /test/DEF230548/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
Error happens

I am making Django app.Django version is 1.8 .
I wrote in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name=‘home’),
    url(‘test/(?P<id>[\w.-]+)/', views.test, name=‘test’),
]
```

in views.py

```
def home(request):
     ・
　　  ・
　　  ・
    test(request,id)
    template = loader.get_template('top.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

def test(request,id):
    try:
        dir_path = "static/data/“
        print("HERE1")
        if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
            os.makedirs(dir_path)

    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print("HERE2")
        print(e)
        template = loader.get_template('data.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

When I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/DEF230548/, the error happens.
print("HERE1") is shown in terminal, but static/data/ is not made.Can’t I call 2 8000ports url?How should I fix this?

Full Traceback is

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/DEF230548/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ‘home’]
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py" in _new_conn
  141.                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py" in create_connection
  60.     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/socket.py" in getaddrinfo
  745.     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

During handling of the above exception ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  601.                                                   chunked=chunked)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in _make_request
  357.             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/http/client.py" in request
  1239.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/http/client.py" in _send_request
  1285.         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/http/client.py" in endheaders
  1234.         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/http/client.py" in _send_output
  1026.         self.send(msg)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/http/client.py" in send
  964.                 self.connect()

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py" in connect
  166.         conn = self._new_conn()

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py" in _new_conn
  150.                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)

During handling of the above exception (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x114530ef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py" in send
  440.                     timeout=timeout

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  639.                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py" in increment
  388.             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

During handling of the above exception (HTTPConnectionPool(host=‘test’, port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /test/DEF230548/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x114530ef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/xxx/home/views.py" in test
  67.     res = get_data(id, ‘user’)

File "/Users/xxx/xxx/home/views.py" in get_data
  25.     response = requests.get(base_url, params={}

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py" in get
  72.     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py" in request
  58.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in request
  508.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in send
  640.         history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in <listcomp>
  640.         history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in resolve_redirects
  218.                     **adapter_kwargs

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in send
  618.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py" in send
  508.             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

Exception Type: ConnectionError at /test/DEF230548/
Exception Value: HTTPConnectionPool(host=‘test’, port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /test/DEF230548/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x114530ef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

Comment: The error you gave is not caused by the code you gave us. Please add all relevant code and the error traceback of the uncaught exception.

Comment: @KlausD. I added full traceback.If you know something,please help me

Comment: You left out the most important lines of your code. Add the code from your `views.py` that is referenced in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

For your `urls.py`, replace the punctuation *‘* to *'*, and try again:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^test/(?P<id>[\w.-]+)/$', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

Comment: thank you for your ans,i wrote your codes but same error happens.If you know somethig please help me

Comment: Maybe you can send all your code of this project to my email.